# Block outgoing caller ID on Nokia 7.2

Tags: android-10

How can I block outgoing caller ID on a Nokia 7.2 with Android One 10?

I've tried to do the following:

- Open the phone app
- Click the three dots menu, choose settings

Now I see many options, including *Caller ID and Spam*. I don't see any option to block Caller ID.

Comment: `*31#<number_to_call>` suppresses the number *for this one call.* There are some "number prefixer" apps available which you could use to automate that rule-based or completely. You could also ask your provider to permanently suppress it if you wish.

Comment: On my previous phone I could set this manually at the network level, for the time being, then undo it. I prefer that over another caller app.

Comment: Sure, that's why I mentioned that [USSD code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data). You can also use that *for all subsequent calls* if you don't follow it by a number, see the table on the linked Wikipedia page. This makes the solution device-independent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `*67*` followed by the number you intend to call and end with a `#`. This works for me as my number gets shown as anonymous on the other phone I am calling. I hope this helps.

Comment: That's funny if that really works – because `67` is for "call divert when busy" – and the number you pass is where incoming calls are being diverted to, see the [code table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data#Code_table). But then, that starts with a double-asterisk – so yours might be a provider-specific addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [USSD codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) to achieve this, regardless of the device you use. For example:

```
*31#<number_to_call>
```

will suppress the display of your number for this single call. You can also use that *for all subsequent calls* if you don't follow it by a number, see the table on the linked Wikipedia page (`*31#` to turn off, `#31#` to turn on, `*#31#` to check status).